# Does Erlang have some functionality for monitoring folder for case when folder was changed?

Tags: erlang

Does Erlang have some functionality for watching folder when it was changed in real time? Eg., we have a folder and try detect if this folder was changed, we call function for start watching of this folder and if folder size was changed will be output some warning. I know that the Erlang have `disksup` but looks like as result will be return free space on disk only and this functionality is a similar like `$ df -k`. I was find some topic for [Python watch](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html) and I’m interesting if Erlang has a similar built-in functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Erlang don't have functionality for monitoring folder from the box, but this can be implemented by custom libraries like:

- https://github.com/synrc/fs
- https://github.com/tsloughter/enotify
- https://github.com/vans163/inotify

Comment: Sure, done. I was thought that my answer will be redundant.

Answer (score 4):

You could take example of that : https://github.com/vans163/rebar3_auto/blob/master/src/rebar3_auto.erl

It is an implementation that does more or less what you want. I don't know if there is a more integrated way of doing it.

Comment: Interesting point, thanks for answer. Looks like revar3_auto is use the enotify custom library for watch folder implementation. But I'm more interested in similar functionality what maybe already implemented inside of Erlang - of course, if such a functional exists at all in Erlang.

Comment: @Viacheslav the state of the [ERL-242](https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-242) ticket may indicate that there's such thing natively implemented right now

Comment: @JoséM the ticket has status `Unresolved` this mean that - this still not implemented in the Erlang and also Erlang team is looking for nice contribution. But, in any case this ticket what you found is also helpful. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Oops, there should be a 'no' between 'there's' and 'such' in my previous comment, shame on me